# How to add categorical variable, college, for someone who has a BA, MA, PhD already coded in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that already contains dummy variables for "BA", "MA, and "PHD", where 1= individual has the degree and 0= individual does not have the degree.

How do I add a new dummy variable to my data frame for having a bachelor's degree or higher?

My data frame's name is college and so far I have tried different variations of

```
college$baplus <- if else(college["BA"],["MA"],["PHD] ==1, 0)
```

BA, MA, and PHD are all atomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a vectorized approach with `rowSums` i.e. subset the columns 'BA', 'MA', 'PHD', get the `rowSums`.  Do a comparsion to check if the sum is greater than 0, then convert the logical to integer with `+` (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
college$baplus <-  +(rowSums(college[c("BA", "MA", "PHD")]) >0)
```

---

The `ifelse` would be without space and it is not really needed, but if we want the syntax

```
college$baplus <- ifelse(rowSums(college[c("BA", "MA", "PHD")]) > 0, 1, 0)
```

---

Or another option is `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (to do the application of function rowwise)

```
college$baplus <- as.integer(apply(college[c("BA", "MA", "PHD")], 1, any))
```

---

It is also reasonable to assume that we need to only compare the column 'BA' because those having higher degrees should have 'BA', so if the intention is to check whether somebody have higher degrees, the `rowSums` comparison would be `> 1`

```
college$baplus <- +(rowSums(college[c("BA", "MA", "PHD")]) > 1)
```